# Sorting points algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, constraints, grouping

To give a brief outline of what I want to do: 
Say we have 14 data points each with random coordinates between (-10, -10) and (10, 10) and they are assigned a colour – either red or blue. I want to be able to form clusters of max 7 points that must satisfy 4 conditions: 
One specifies the max number of red data points that can be in a cluster, one specifies the max number of points in the cluster, another to maximise the number of points in the cluster and the other says that their locations must be close together - i.e we can’t have 2 points inside the cluster (-10, -10) and (10, 10).

To be quite honest I don't even know where to start, I have tried using k-means sorting to organise the data points into clusters but this doesn't satisfy max number of red points constraint.

Comment: can you give an example input and desired output? 14 clusters with single point in each group matches your conditions?

Comment: @trigonom we want to maximise the number of points in each cluster. Just edited the post

Comment: You could attack it as sort of a capacitated facility location problem (well, with two different capacities -- red and overall -- but with an integer programming formulation that's not such a big deal).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Could you expand? So depending on the constraint we formulate an equation that needs to be satisfied and then run through all the different combinations and find the optimal value?

Comment: Yeah, the capacities enforce the per-cluster limits, and the facility opening cost dictates how many facilities/clusters you want versus how tight they are.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Ok, so I've done a bit of research but I'm not sure how the opening cost will dictate how many clusters there are? We can't have the same datapoint in multiple clusters. I think your onto something though, could you give an example as a solution and I can mark this post resolved? Thanks :)

Comment: It's indirect control. If you just want to specify the number of clusters, then capacitated k-means is better. I'll try to post something in the next day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some sample Python using [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/integer_opt) to get you started.

```
import collections
import math
import random

from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


Point = collections.namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y", "is_red"])


def random_point():
    return Point(random.uniform(-10, 10), random.uniform(-10, 10), random.randrange(2))


def close_enough(p, q):
    return math.hypot(p.x - q.x, p.y - q.y) <= 5


def assign(points, max_clusters, max_overall, max_red):
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("SCIP")
    variables = {
        (i, j): solver.BoolVar("")
        for i in range(len(points))
        for j in range(max_clusters)
    }
    for i in range(len(points)):
        solver.Add(sum(variables[i, j] for j in range(max_clusters)) == 1)
    for i1, p1 in enumerate(points):
        for i2, p2 in enumerate(points):
            if not close_enough(p1, p2):
                for j in range(max_clusters):
                    solver.Add(variables[i1, j] + variables[i2, j] <= 1)
    for j in range(max_clusters):
        solver.Add(sum(variables[i, j] for (i, p) in enumerate(points)) <= max_overall)
    for j in range(max_clusters):
        solver.Add(
            sum(variables[i, j] for (i, p) in enumerate(points) if p.is_red) <= max_red
        )
    status = solver.Solve()
    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        groups = [[] for j in range(max_clusters)]
        for i, p in enumerate(points):
            for j in range(max_clusters):
                if variables[i, j].SolutionValue():
                    groups[j].append(p)
        return groups


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(assign([random_point() for i in range(14)], 7, 7, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure what the first two for loops are for? What do they constrain, I understand the rest.

Comment: @TomBushell in order the for loops are (1) make a variable for each point->cluster assignment (2) make sure that each point is assigned to exactly one cluster (3) make sure that no two faraway points belong to the same cluster (4) limit the number of points in each cluster (5) limit the number of red points in each cluster (6) extract the solution.